# How to fix 'ClassNotFoundException: brave.propagation.CurrentTraceContext$ScopeDecorator'?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I used spring-cloud-starter-sleuth in my project. Then when it starts, it will show ClassNotFoundException:brave.propagation.CurrentTraceContext$ScopeDecorator

This is a very beginning project with Spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE and spring cloud Greenwich.RC2; It ran fine before I add the dependency 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth';

I start a new project with only spring-cloud-starter-sleuth in it(spring cloud INITIALIZR demo), but it still not work;

The POM is:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

The code is just：

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and the execption is：
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: brave.propagation.CurrentTraceContext$ScopeDecorator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

Comment: Maybe a corrupt download in the maven cache

Comment: your pom is not valid (for me/the part we see): `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` is missing version! ..and when I apply @amaljoyc solution (`2.1.0.RELEASE`) - cannot reproduce/works like charm!

Answer (score 2):

or you can use the spring cloud `Greenwich.RELEASE` version in order to fix your problem of ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

add the below dependency into your dependencyManagement section and try again!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```